# WebRequest: Content-Type = text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1 : 'The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.'

Tags: c#, webrequest, iso-8859-1

The server where I need to POST only accepts "iso-8859-1". I don't know if I'm doing it right because whenever I'm getting the response of the web request it give me the error "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Please see code below.

```
var someGeneratedString = "This_is a generated string!"
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://******"); // This is private, sorry.
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(someGeneratedString);
string xx = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(rawRequest);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);

request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(isoBytes, 0, isoBytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

When I remove the "    dataStream.Write(isoBytes, 0, isoBytes.Length);"
It is not giving me an error.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
If you have more questions please ask me. Thanks in advance!

Just an additional, some of the answers in the same question is to put Security Protocol.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768
                                               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Event with this, it's still giving me the error.

Comment: Try `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Tried that already sir. But still not working.

Comment: Did you set it **before** or **after** calling `WebRequest.Create` ?

Comment: By the way, Your code is somehow strange, you're not using the `xx` variable. That also means you're not doing anything with `byteArray` or `someGeneratedString`.

Comment: Set it before     webrequest.create

Comment: Thanks for your help. Already found a work around :D